# Neo4j Cypher query with sub select

Tags: neo4j, cypher, jqassistant

I am trying to find a query for my graph which I created by jqassistant. But I just can't figure it out. My data looks like this:

I have several nodes representing a artifact: (Each row is a node)

```
name        version
===================
projectOne     001
projectTwo     001
projectOne     002
projectTwo     002
projectOne     009
projectOne     004
projectOne     029
projectTwo     003
projectTwo     010
```

What my query should return is two nodes:

```
projectOne  029
projectTwo  010
```

So I want the newest version of this nodes distinct by name. I know how to use DISTINCT and ORDER BY but I just can't figure out how to combine those two to get the desired output. Any ideas?

My final goal is to mark the newest versions. Then I want to point out every newest artifact which depends on artifacts which are not marked as newest.

Another possible solution to reach this would be to create a chain of predecessors. Then every artifact with no incoming predecessor would be the latest version. But that implies the same problem as I have with selecting the newest ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all relevant nodes have the `Foo` label, the query is very simple:

```
MATCH (n:Foo)
RETURN n.name, MAX(n.version);
```

The `MAX` aggregation function finds the maximum version for each distinct name.

Comment: Oh. Looks quite easy. I'll try it out later this evening and mark the answer if it works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nice and easy solution! Note that this only works if the version attribute of your artifacts creates a natural order, i.e. if you use another versioning scheme like 1.10.0 things might break.